# Get index of parameter of element in list

Tags: c#, list, linq

It is hard to explain my problem writing it in "normal" language so I'll just post my code (it would be easier to understand):

I have my class `File`:

```
public class File
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
}
```

So I created a list of `files`:

```
var files = new List<File>();
```

and, I have populated it with data.

Now I have a `string` (and only that.) I would like to find the index of the element containing that `string` in my list.

Something like:

```
int index = files.IndexOf(new File
        {
            string.Empty,
            myString,
            string.Empty,
            null
        });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `List` class has a method called [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__), that takes a [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) as a parameter.

You can use it like this:

```
var index = files.FindIndex(f => f.Name == myString);
```

It will return the index of the first element that matches the predicate or -1 if no such element was found.

Comment: This works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to find the index of the first element with the `Name` property equals to `myString` variale:

```
var index = files.IndexOf(files.Where(x => x.Name == myString).FirstOrDefault());
```

Or even more simpler way:

```
var index = files.IndexOf(files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == myString));`
```

Both return -1 if no such element was found.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I find all instances with `Name` containing the `myString`, then, use `IndexOf` to find his index in the list. The result is a collection index of the instances

```
var indexs = files.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(myString)).Select(ft=> files.IndexOf(ft));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `foreach` loop like

```
int pos = -1;
foreach(File file in files)
{
  pos++;
  if(file.Name == "string")
    break;
}
```

Comment: because `FindIndex` does the same with just one line of code, with the same efficiency? Also, you should initialize `pos` at -1, otherwise, you'll get a false positive if the file was not found.

Comment: @ZoharPeled setting `pos = -1` is correct .. Thanks